# problem with copying Dynamic result

Tags: front-end, dynamic

After running below code

```
   DynamicModule[{temp},
     data = Range[10];
     temp = {};
     Column[{
       Button["reset", temp = {}],
       TogglerBar[Dynamic[temp], data, Appearance -> "Horizontal" -> {Automatic, 5}],
       Dynamic[temp]
     }]
   ]
```

I got

[image]

Now I want to copy the dynamically generated list and paste it elsewhere. But I found sometimes it works, sometimes it is not. You can see below gif

[image]

What is wrong with my code? Why sometimes it gives `temp$$`, sometimes not? How to make dynamic results easy to copy?

---

**Update**

With Kuba's method to view "SelectionData", it is clear what is going on, see below gif. **So proper selection will give expected result instead of `temp$$`**

[image]

Comment: It is probably a subtle problem with what you really select, if whole `DynamicBox` or not. To achieve a stable behavior you can use `InputField@Dynamic[temp]` for example.

Comment: Yes, I think, @Kuba is right about whether you select the whole `DynamicBox` or its contents. -- The menu command Cell > Show Expression will reveal what you actually pasted.

Comment: Hi, @MichaelE2. But I can not see any difference between two cases by looking at  " Show Expression". where is the difference?

Comment: @matheorem with ShowExpression you only see what is written in a notebook file. There is another layer, on that FE really displays, so `DynamicBox` is there but FE keeps track what it really represents. In this case a box representation of `temp`. More or less ;)

Comment: Syntax highlighting can assist your selection process. If the cursor is placed directly after the `}`, then `{ }` will be highlighted and you'll be selecting the right thing. If the cursor is placed too far after `}`, then there is no syntax highlighting and you'll be selecting the `DynamicBox`. One can use the arrow key to move to the correct position. Double-clicking on `{` or `}` also results in a correct selection.

Comment: Hi, @Karsten7.  You are right. Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Quick fix:

To achieve a stable behavior you can use e.g. `InputField @ Dynamic[temp]`.

#### More about the issue:

It is probably a subtle problem with what you really select, if whole `DynamicBox` or not.

To see what is going on you can use

```
Dynamic @ InputForm @ CurrentValue @ "SelectionData"
```

and check what is selected in certain steps, sometimes it is

> ```
> DynamicBox[ToBoxes[temp$$, StandardForm], ....] (*displayed as `temp$$`*)
> ```

and sometimes a `RowBox` with numbers. In the latter case you got what you were expecting.

Comment: `InputField` is great! upvoted! Thank you so much! I need more time to understand the remaining part : )

Comment: "SelectionData" works like magic, very interesting : )

Comment: @matheorem I'm glad it fits yor needs :) Thanks for the accept.